# Python 3 print to file with mix of " and ' in string

Tags: python, html, string

I am creating an HTML output file using vanilla Python 3 and I wish to use the multi-tab layout (http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs_close) to help organize my presentation.

When trying to print: `'  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'Faults')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>'`  I run into a situation where I need to include (') and (") characters in the string. I have tried to only use (") characters inside the string and use (') to define the string, however this breaks the html functionality of the code.

If I use `'partial string {}Faults{} more string'.format("'","'")` I see this output:

```
'  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, \'Faults\')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>)'
```

Similarly if I attempt to join strings together,

```
b = '  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, '
c = "'Faults'"
d = ')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>)
('').join([b,c,d])
```

I get the exact same thing as my first attempt.

```
'  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, \'Faults\')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>)'
```

Is there any way to get around this issue while printing to a file?
Thank you.

Comment: _"I get the exact same thing as my first attempt."_ Is that what you get when you print it? When you look at the result in the interactive prompt? Or when you write it to a file and open the file with Notepad? Each of these may display differently from the others.

Comment: `\'` is an escape sequence and is correct. `'singled \'quote\' example'` = `singled 'quote' example`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, \'Faults\')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>'`

You need to escape single quotes in single quotes. If you write this to a file, it will be how you want it.

Or use `'''  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, \'Faults\')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>'''`

Notice the triple quotes?

Interesting article about escaping in Python: [Learn Python the hard way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html)

Comment: This really helped! Thanks for pointing out the resources I can read to learn more. I appreciate that. I've worked with \n before but didn't think about any other related options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the triple `'''` or `"""` characters. This is a multiline string (and docstring) in python.

E.g:

```
'''
hello world! I can write ' and " and also " and ' "''""'''"""
'''
```

Comment: It's not a comment; Python still has to create the string object defined by the literal.

Comment: Yes, it is a document string.

Comment: Single-line strings can also be used as doc strings, and multiline strings can be assigned to names (`v = """..."""`). The two concepts are entirely orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your `format` approach; what you are seeing is just Python's default representation of the string. Use `print '...'.format("'", "'")`, and it should look as you expect.

```
>>> print '  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, {}Faults{})"><b>Faults</b></a></li>'.format("'", "'")
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'Faults')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>
```

However, you can avoid using `format` by simply using a multiline string literal (`"""..."""` or `'''...'''`), which can accommodate unescaped quotation marks of either flavor.

```
>>> print '''  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'Faults')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>'''
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'Faults')"><b>Faults</b></a></li>
```